# return false in c# page of javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, return

how can do script return false in the C# page. I have called javascript function c# page.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "event", "val();", true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is not possible as you have already get interaction to server so it won't work, if you want to do return false, then u should do all this using jquery